# How to find smallest number without using java sort()

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

How to find smallest number without using java sort() method and sorting techniques from Integer array List? I used `Collections.min()`, my snippet is:

```
public class SmallestNum {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of Array::");
        int sizee=sc.nextInt();
        List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<sizee;i++) {
            numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        //Collections.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println(" Search value:");
        int num=sc.nextInt();
        Integer mini=Collections.min(numbers);
        System.out.println("Minimum Value is:"+mini);
        for(int i=0;i<sizee;i++) {
            System.out.println("Minimum:"+(mini));
            *if(mini.equals(numbers)) {
                int smallSec=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            /*System.out.println(" Search value:");
            int num=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(numbers.get(num-1));
            */
        }
    }
}
```

This program not working. Please suggest alternative logic. I don't understand if user want to search next smallest number how to do ?

Comment: if your program does not work, do you get any error?

Comment: @MadConan codereview is for code improvements, not as a platform to debug your code.

Comment: **if** (a > b) **then** swap(a,b) :: at nested for-loop

Comment: `if(mini.equals(numbers))` compares an `Integer` to a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Is this part of code should be commented:*if(mini.equals(numbers)) {
                int smallSec=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            } ? Seems like it won't compile.

Comment: i m not getting any error

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I misread the question as, "This program is working" instead of "This program not working."  Deleting my comment.

Comment: Are you trying to find the minimum element or **the second**minimum element in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.min` will directly give you minimum value. You need to do additional comparisons. But if you want to find minimum number without using out of the box method you could simply use this logic

```
Integer minNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(Integer i :  numbers){
    if(i < minNum) {
        minNum = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("Minimum Value is: " + minNum);
```

Considering that you are reading a "Search value" I assume you are looking for something else. Please give more details about what you are trying to achieve.

**Update based on comment.**

For this you could use [quick select algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). The program would be

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmallestNum {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of Array::");
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(" Search value:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        if (n > 0 && n <= size) {
            int nthSmall = select(numbers, 0, size - 1, n);
            System.out.println("Minimum Value is: " + nthSmall);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
        }
    }

    private static int select(List<Integer> list, int left, int right, int n) {
        int pivotIndex = getPivotIndex(list, left, right);
        if (pivotIndex == n - 1) {
            return list.get(pivotIndex);
        }
        if ((n - 1) < pivotIndex) {
            return select(list, left, pivotIndex - 1, n);
        } else {
            return select(list, pivotIndex + 1, right, n);
        }

    }

    private static int getPivotIndex(List<Integer> list, int left, int right) {
        int pivot = list.get((left + right) / 2);
        while (left < right) {
            while (list.get(left) < pivot) {
                left++;
            }
            while (list.get(right) > pivot) {
                right--;
            }

            if (left < right) {
                int temp = list.get(left);
                list.set(left, list.get(right));
                list.set(right, temp);
                left++;
                right--;
            }

        }
        return left;
    }
}
```

Comment: if numbers={0,4,1,5,6,9}; this is our array ,if user enter 3 ,we need to display third smallest integer in array i.t op will be 4 only

Comment: using your snippet it gives op   Enter size of Array::(5)
6
4
22
1
2
 Search value:
2
Minimum Value is:1
Minimum:1
Minimum Value is: 2
Minimum:1
Minimum Value is: 1
Minimum:1
Minimum Value is: 1
Minimum:1
Minimum Value is: 1
Minimum:1
Minimum Value is: 4

Comment: /* Thats what i want */

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     long delta = System.nanoTime();

     int[] inputArray = new int[]{0,4,1,5,6,9};
     int n = 3;

     System.out.println("the " + n + "th min is " + getNthMin(inputArray, n));
     System.out.println();
  }

  private static int getNthMin(int[] array, int n) {
     int nthMin = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     int[] tmpArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int minIndex = 0;
        int min = tmpArray[minIndex];
        for (int j = 1; j < tmpArray.length; j++) {
           if (tmpArray[j] < min) {
              min = tmpArray[j];
              minIndex = j;
           }
        }
        tmpArray[minIndex] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        if (min > nthMin) {
           nthMin = min;
        }
     }
     return nthMin;
  }
```

Or using a list to iterate over a less number of elements:

```
  private static int getNthMin2(Integer[] array, int n) {
     int nthMin = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Integer min = list.get(0);
        for (Integer value : list) {
           if (value < min) {
              min = value;
           }
        }
        list.remove(min);

        if (min > nthMin) {
           nthMin = min;
        }
     }
     return nthMin;
  }
```